# OpenTok Web: Custom properties when publishing Stream

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

Trying to publish a stream with custom `name` using documentation:

```js
session = OT.initSession(partnerId, sessionId);
session.connect(token, error => {
  if (error) alert(error.message);
  else {
    const publisher = OT.initPublisher('mobile', {
      name: 'myCustomName',
      width: 720,
      height: 1280 // tried resolution: "720x1280" without luck
    });
    session.publish(publisher);
  }
});
```

Source: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Session.html#publish

I need this property to identify a publisher server-side and perform required actions in database.
Though I get Tokbox callback response in NodeJS but `name` is always empty:

[image]

What's wrong with the code and where to find the actual version?
Also how can one set custom names to streams/sessions for identifying purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

Are you getting any callbacks with `event: 'streamCreated'` or `event: 'streamDestroyed'`?

Those events will contain a `stream` object that will contain the `name` property for that stream.

You can see the actual JSON payloads for each callback at https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/session-monitoring/#monitoring-streams

If you'd like to see the name data in the `connectionCreated` and `connectionDestroyed` callbacks then you could pass in the name when you generate the token for the user.  Then the `connection` object would contain the name within its `data` property.

You can find a NodeJS example for generating the token with the name data at https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/node/#generating-tokens

Comment: Nope, I get only "archive" events from that callback. My ultimate goal was to get the archive url for further saving in my storage, so I subscribed to "archive" events in my dashboard. I will try to pass values inside token payloads as you proposed. But this step of your workflow is a bit counter-intuitive. Also it doesn't affect resolution as I expected.

Comment: Any ideas on how to set video resolution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ah. You likely setup the Archive Callback URL and not the Session Monitoring callback.

You can set a callback Url for the session events on your project page. It will look like:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1228996/68154246-b9003600-ff0c-11e9-8cd4-49ed4815411d.png

Comment: To set the resolution you'd want to modify your initPublisher with the option `resolution: '1280x720'`

You can see more info at https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/publish-stream/js/#setting_resolution. Including valid values.